# attach website username to paypal IPN product_id

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

i have IPN data sending back the correct info, i have the product id and i also have a text box for user's to write in their in-game-name in on my website.

im stuggling to attach the username input with the IPN product_id. what i want it to do is when the user clicks the paypal button, it process's the transaction and if approved the username entered from the website and product_id get placed into a array or something that i can later put into my database

im quite new to php and html please bare with me

Comment: This is easy, just put the User-id  of the logged in user inside the html of the ipn Button code. The Paypal documentation explain this. Then Paypal will send this value together with all other data to your in script and you can update your database on this. So you will know who bought the product.  Please post your button HTML and your PHP Code of the IPN target so that we ca  help you better.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a PayPal transaction, pass a variable named `custom` with the values you want to store as part of the transaction.

For old-style HTML integrations that use no API or JS, this is documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#payment-transaction-variables

---

IPN is very old and clunky. Crrent PayPal integrations don't use IPN at all, but rather two routes on your server that call the PayPal API -- one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

When you do that capture call you get an immediate response of success/failure and can update your database/system accordingly. Thus there is no need to wait around for PayPal to send you an IPN notification.

Those two routes on your server should return JSON data (and only JSON data) when called. The approval flow to pair with them is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You can add POST data values to your fetch request.